# Vim make creates new file with Quickfix - Errorformat

Tags: vim, makefile, scanf

This seems to be caused by errorformat being wrong, but I'm not sure what's causing it looking at the current value.

Result of `:make %`

```
/Users/seanhess/sandbox/typescript/main.ts (62,15): Expected ';'
"~/sandbox/typescript/main.ts " [New File]
```

Current value of `set errorformat?`

```
errorformat= %#%f(%l\,%c): %m
```

If it helps, here's the bundle where it is defined. https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim/blob/master/compiler/typescript.vim

Comment: Should it be this?  `errorformat= %#%f (%l\,%c): %m` Is this a regex? Can I put a \s* in there instead of the space?

Comment: Ok, I know it's scanf now. How can I put an optional space there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `%#` is equivalent to `*` in regex

```
errorformat=\ %#%f\ %#(%l\\\,%c):\ %m
```